# Typescript does not detect type error

Tags: typescript

I have the following code snippets:

File [router-data.ts#L46](https://github.com/ManfredSteiner/kicad/blob/38629bbe56938c427e24f6e8808ad27f5c455edb/rpi-atmega324-modbus-gateway-min/software/rpi-ts-froniusmeter/server/src/routers/router-data.ts#L46)

```
...
const fd = FroniusMeter.getInstance(req.query.address ? req.query.address : 1);
....
```

The method `getInstance()` is defined in file [fronius-meter.ts#L51](https://github.com/ManfredSteiner/kicad/blob/38629bbe56938c427e24f6e8808ad27f5c455edb/rpi-atmega324-modbus-gateway-min/software/rpi-ts-froniusmeter/server/src/devices/fronius-meter.ts#L51)

```
public static getInstance (id: string): FroniusMeter {
    if (id.startsWith('/dev')) {
        debug.info('...');
    }
    let rv = ModbusDevice.getInstance(id);
    if (!rv) {
        rv = ModbusDevice.instances.find( (d) => (d instanceof FroniusMeter) && (d.address === +id) );
    }
    return rv instanceof FroniusMeter ? rv : null;
}
```

The sources are transpiled without warning or error ([tsconfig.json](https://github.com/ManfredSteiner/kicad/blob/38629bbe56938c427e24f6e8808ad27f5c455edb/rpi-atmega324-modbus-gateway-min/software/rpi-ts-froniusmeter/server/tsconfig.json)), but executing throws an exception `TypeError: id.startsWith is not a function`.

The reason is clear, the call of `getInstance()` uses a number as parameter, but the method is written for a string as parameter. Therefore `id.startsWith(...` throws an error.

My question, why did typescript transpilation not print out some warning or error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this passes is very simple, and comes from the type of `req.query` which is `any`. Since this is `any` any property access will also be of type `any`. So `req.query.address` is of type `any`.

If conditional the two branches of a conditional expression have different types the conditional expression type will evaluate to the union of the two

```
let x = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "A" : 0; // x is string | number
```

However in a union `any` will always eat up any other types so a conditional in which either branch has an `any` will be typed as `any`

```
let y: any;
let x = Math.random() > 0.5 ? y : 0; // x is any
```

So in your call `req.query.address ? req.query.address : 1` is of type `any` and thus assignable to `string`.

And this is why `any` should be avoided like the plague especially by library writers.

Answer (score 7):

The reason is simple, [`req.query` is defined as `any`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts#L439). So `req.query.address` is also defined as any.

let's take this code:

```
let f: TypeA;
let g: TypeB;
let bool: boolean;
let x = bool ? g : f;
```

Typescript will infer the type of x to be `TypeA | TypeB`.

So, the type of the expression `req.query.address ? req.query.address : 1` is technically `any | number`, however this is just `any`.

[In typescript 3.0 a new type called `unknown` is supposed to be added](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24439), which should solve this.